# Qt4 PySide: QPainter cross-platform pixel accuracy

Tags: python, qt

In trying to track down the differences in rendering between my two target platforms (Linux and OSX), I came across an apparent inconsistency in the way ellipses are rendered on each platform.

Here are the results: [Linux vs OSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYM3x.jpg)

And here is the program I used to generate this:

```
from PySide.QtGui import (QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, 
                          QMainWindow, QPixmap, QPainter)
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)
    view.scale(15, 15)

    pix = QPixmap(200, 50)
    pix.fill(Qt.white)
    p = QPainter(pix)
    p.setPen(Qt.black)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        p.drawEllipse(0, 0, i, i)
        p.translate(i+5, 0)
    p.end()
    pixItem = scene.addPixmap(pix)

    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setCentralWidget(view)
    win.resize(700, 200)
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is this the result of my method of drawing or an incompatibility in the rendering engines?

My goal is to have a program that can color pixels accurately. For example, zoom in and color pixels individually or using a circular "brush", color a group of them (this is how I discovered the difference in rendering).

Is there a better way to approach this problem rather than drawing to pixmaps and relying on Qt for scaling pixels properly?